# Distort image in css3 of 4 corners

Tags: css, image, distortion

I look 1 item for learning, fun. I would like have the same effect in CSS3 as in flash. http://www.rubenswieringa.com/code/as3/flex/DistortImage/

When I look in internet examples, I found only skew or rotate. I would like to have option distort image of corner image.

Comment: you can do this webgl, not sure about pure css

Answer (score 2):

It's not trivial to do that – there are at least 3 options though. I'm not backing them up with a how to as that's hard and much longer than would fit here. (plus would take hours without stumbling across a library to do it)

1. Use `canvas`. Split the image into bits and draw them in the right place. You could either use the 2D or 3D (WebGL) context depending on what you are doing.
2. Use CSS 3D transforms. Make lots of divs, set the image to be the background image with the offsets to make it look like one image. Position them using 3D transforms to have the effect required.
3. Use a custom shader (only in super new browsers). http://html.adobe.com/webstandards/csscustomfilters/cssfilterlab/ has some examples of similar things.

In short, there isn't a simple way at all.

Comment: I found this: [link](http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=5)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there ***is*** a rather simple way.

[Distort.js](https://github.com/isuttell/distort)